# How to override same css class in ReactJS using css-to-mui-loader like standard css

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am very new to Material Design. Currently i am exploring Material UI with ReactJS. Basically i am trying to replicate the same behavior as Standard CSS behavior. Please find my issue below,

I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-to-mui-loader

I have created css file as (styles.css) below,

```
.button {
background: $(theme.palette.secondary.main);
padding: 2su; /* Material UI spacing units */
}

.button:hover {
background: $(theme.palette.primary.light);
}

.button {
background: #f08373;
padding: 3su; /* Material UI spacing units */
text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

My react code as below,

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import style from './style.css';
import classNames from 'classnames'

const MyComponent = (props) =>{
const { classes} = props
console.log(classes)
return(
<Button className={classNames(classes.button, classes.label)}>
Click Me

)
}

export default withStyles(style)(MyComponent)
```

When i try to run my code, i am getting Error like,

Failed to compile.

./src/MyComponent.js
Attempted import error: './style.css' does not contain a default export (imported as 'style').

Here i am trying to override the css class name .button. Compiler throws an error.

When i modified the same css as below,

```
.button {
background: $(theme.palette.secondary.main);
padding: 2su; /* Material UI spacing units */
}

.button:hover {
background: $(theme.palette.primary.light);
}

.button {
text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

[css-to-mui-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-to-mui-loader) Successfully merged two .button class as one.

Can you please help to me to override the css class name using [css-to-mui-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-to-mui-loader)

Answer (score 1):

When importing css files, you don't import it as a module, but like the following:

```
import './myStyle.css';
```

Let me know if this helps and if you have any more questions.

Comment: Thank for your reply. Here i am using withStyles material ui function to apply my styles. so in this case i have to pass as a module like withStyles(mycss)(mycomponent). Can you help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted the same issue in GitHub. css-to-mui-loader library owner fixed the issue and released new version. Please find the link below for more details.

[css-to-mui-loader/issue](https://github.com/mcdougal/css-to-mui-loader/issues/1)